# Why my Polymer2 build size is large as compared to Angular5 build?

Tags: angular, build, polymer, polymer-2.x

To choose `polymer2` over `angular` framework, because I read from some blogs that polymer contribute less build size for prod as compared to angular2/5 build,

I have created two demo projects one for angular5 and second for polymer2.

For angular5 I run

> `npm new angular5-demo --service-worker --routing`

and for polymer2

> `polymer init`
>
> Press the down arrow until polymer-2-starter-kit is highlighted and press the enter / return key to select.

and when i'm running projects by

`ng serve --prod` and
`polymer serve --open`

and it's showing large size of polymer project as compared to angular

> transfered data:
>
> angular : 60-70kb
>
> polymer : 50-204kb

rencenty i went though a many blogs for polymer and they are claiming that polymer build size is 4-5 times less as compared to angular

one blog link is mentioned [here](https://medium.com/@realabhijeet4u/angular-2-0-vs-polymer-f45a4f539238)

So, is there something i'm missing to build for prod in polymer project from polymer site.

please help me to find out the issue.

update:

**Polymer**

> `polymer build`
>
> `serve -g /build/es6-bundle`
>
> transferred data : 56.3KB
>
> bundle size of zip file : 204KB

**Angular**

> `npm start --prod`
>
> transferred data : 64KB
>
> bundle size of zip file : 67KB

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you're doing a fair comparison because:

- The `ng serve --prod` command builds the production version of the code, including minification. The `polymer serve --open` command serves the raw unminified version of the project (no build done at all here). For `polymer-cli` to serve the build output directory, that directory must be specified as an argument.
- You labeled the comparison "transferred data", so I'm assuming you compared the total bytes downloaded for the *entire app* and not specifically just the framework/library source (and you confirmed this in a comment). Unless you built an Angular clone of `polymer-2-starter-kit`, the size comparison will be skewed because they're two completely different apps.
- The article you linked is comparing the size of Angular and Polymer *themselves*; not the apps created. Also note the versions are different from what you're testing, so the size difference may no longer be accurate. Here's a screenshot from the article/blog:

  [image: screenshot from article]

---

The production build of `polymer-2-starter-kit` (generated from `polymer build` command) can be found in `build/es6-bundled/`. To serve that build output, run `polymer serve build/es6-bundled`. You'll notice the first view of the production build is 56KB transferred on Chrome and 387KB on Firefox (because the needed Web Components polyfills are loaded in the latter case).

Comment: Thanks for reply, but build of angular prod is nearly 67kb. steal it doesn't make in large difference in size. and yes i'm minifying polymer app by `"preset": "es6-bundled",` in my polymer.json file

Comment: How exactly are you measuring the sizes of Angular vs Polymer?

Comment: i measured both by build size and transferred size. transferred size means total bytes download in network tab of browser.

Comment: Ok, I assumed that's what you were doing. Even if you built the Polymer app with the preset, you're not serving that build output (given that you said you used `polymer serve --open`), so you're not seeing the size of the production build. But still, you're comparing two completely different apps, so the comparison wouldn't provide any real meaning.

Comment: for production build i'm comparing build file size manually by creating .zip file. and let me check polymer size by `serve -s build`

Comment: serving by `serve -s build/es6-bundle` polymer transferring data 56.3KB.
and zip file of `es6-bundle` is 204KB.

while in case of angular, zip file is of 67KB and transfer data is 64KB